# How to revoke user permission on Socialite

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I want to revoke the permission user gave me on Facebook, if he denied to give me Facebook's email. How can I do that?. I'm using Socialite on Laravel 5.2

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}

DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```

This is explained in the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revoking

You can revoke permissions and even the general authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you.

Reading the Facebook Graph API documentation, I found the same orientacions as luschn, but it did not solve my problem.

How I solved it

```
use GuzzleHttp \ Client;

$ http = new Client ();
$ req = $ http-> delete ("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/{USER ID} / permissions? access_token = {API TOKEN}");
```

I found the token API on the token generator: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

So I made the direct request, I believe it is not the best form but solved it.

I hope this can help you and other person.